# PhantomJS CasperJS cannot load Google Maps SDK on Linux but on Mac

Tags: javascript, google-maps, phantomjs, casperjs

I have problems to access a page with CasperJS which includes the Google Maps JS SDK.

The main problem is that "google" is not defined. So the Google javascript doesn't load.

My simple example:

test.js

```
casper.start("http://localhost/test.html);
casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(5000, function(){});
});
casper.then(function() {
    var data = this.evaluate(function() {
        return (window.google == undefined) ? "not working" : "working";
    });
    this.echo(data);
});
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-MAPS-KEY"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

On Mac:

```
$ casperjs --version && phantomjs --version
1.1.4
2.1.1
$ casper.js test.js
working
```

On Linux Server (Ubuntu 16.04.1):

```
$ casperjs --version && phantomjs --version
1.1.4
2.1.1
$ casper.js test.js
not working
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Casper related? Do you perhaps have limitation in your google api based on host?

Can you add handlers for these 2 events `onResourceError` and `onError`. What do they say?

Comment: Thanks. Through onResourceError I got the error message:
`{"errorCode":6,"errorString":"SSL handshake failed","id":2,"status":null,"statusText":null,"url":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=..."}`
...
`--ignore-ssl-errors=true` solves it as workaround, but have to find out why this happens on my linux box.

Comment: As far as I can remember there was an error with SSL in history of phantomJS, cannot recall exactly now, but glad you solved it

Comment: Google is currently migrating to new root certificates as mentioned in this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936. Check if your linux box has all required certificates to be able to communicate with Google servers.